# How would I include my name and details in the html/css/jquery coding of a website that I am designing so that it is not editable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, security

I would like to protect my website's code and prevent others from using my coding by including my name , email address and copyright as permanent code. Is this possible?
I would like to engineer it in such a way that the code is not editable and so that my details appear in only the coding and not on the website. Also I was wondering whether their was a way to password protect or hide segments of code from public viewing?
Maybe I could add my logo and if the user attempts to remove it , the coding doesn't function properly?

Comment: Pretty much nope. You would have to make it deep and convoluted. The best thing to do is attach a licensing agreement along with your code, so, if removed, the license is broke and you can take legal recourse. Anything else is 100% futile and can be removed at some point.

Comment: But I suppose every programming language must have workarounds and ways to crack and get a hold of an algorithm and then use it. Are their any measures that one can take to hide code?
I remember downloading a plugin that had a portion hidden and so I was unable to modify it to my needs a while back, what could they have been using?

Comment: I like the point that QuackQuaker made in his answer. "Take pride in making good readable and reusable code". Maybe you believe in the saying, "If you're good at something, never do it for free".

Comment: I agree with you 100%. However, let's say you create a groundbreaking algorithm and you would like to keep it confidential or you would like to keep segments of your code from public eyes but still need to have it in your code for the purposes of your private clients. Then how do you take the measures to prevent your code from being misused? I'm not writing from a selfish perspective but rather to gather information and understand the security measures that a web programmer has at their disposal.

Comment: Updated my answer with more information.

Comment: @Delrog If I wrote an algorithm and wanted to keep it secret, I'd host it on my server and allow approved clients to make an API `POST` request to my server with input parameters & an API key and get a JSON response with a solution. Server-side code on YOUR server will only be readable if the server is compromised.

Comment: @LightningDust Pefect answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to put your name, email address etc. in code:

Use comments like this in HTML:

```
<!-- @author:  Some Name -->
<!-- @address: some@email.com -->
```

Or like this in Javascript:

```
/**
 * @author:  Some Name
 * @address: some@email.com
 */
```

### Programmatically preventing users removing those comments:

This is very difficult for client-side code, you can try making functions check if elements are present using a DOM library, but there will always be ways to work around this.

**Obfuscation:**

It is possible to obfuscate [HTML](http://htmlobfuscator.com/) and [JavaScript](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/) code. However, it is equally possible to [de-obfuscate](http://www.kahusecurity.com/2012/revelo-javascript-deobfuscator/) them for a determined attacker.

You may find that it's worth [minifying](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) your JavaScript and CSS instead, which makes them more condensed in order to make your pages load faster and use less traffic. This does have a side effect of making code less readable (and thus, more difficult to steal) but it's still not foolproof.

**Hosted solutions:**

If your site is using server-side code (PHP, ASP, Ruby on Rails etc.), you could consider offering hosted services instead of offering the code. This way, your clients wouldn't be able to modify the site's source code, but you would have to develop a powerful control panel to give them the options they need to operate the software.

### The best option to secure your attribution is a license:

Licensing is probably your best bet, you could distribute the code under something like the [3-clause BSD license](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) which requires anyone using your code to retain an attribution to you. If they remove it you could seek damages through the courts system.

**It's not flawless...**

The issue with trying to force recognition of ownership is that a dedicated abuser will be able to remove any given attribution from code which you distribute to them (by definition, if they have the code, they can edit it).

**But:**

Most legitimate users won't bother. Massive projects like Wordpress, phpBB and Magento rely on nothing more than attribution & licensing to protect their ownership. You'll probably find that you get the recognition you deserve if you create a piece of code worthy of recognition, rather than spend a long time trying to deal with a tiny minority of users who would take advantage of it.

Answer (score 4):

Serverside code is hidden from the user.

It is only the "ouput" that is viewable at the client.

Clienside; The HTML, JS and CSS must be readable by the browser, hence you can not change/hide to a degree that the browser can not read/understand.

**Solution.**

1. You a appropriate licence
2. Obfuscate the code. Just google this. Beware this will not give you the benefits you want. And this only makes it harder to read. 
   This is best for use in javascript.
3. Use A and take pride in making good readable and reusable code.

Comment: "*Clientside code is hidden from the user.*" Did you mean to say serverside?

Comment: Obfuscating is not a good option. If you do want to do this make sure you make a copy of Obfuscated code. If you want to make changes to your code you will be regretting your decision. I learnt this the hard way.

Comment: http://javascriptobfuscator.com/ is very heavy duty Obfuscator. This will pretty much scare away anyone trying to steal your JS

Comment: @AnaMaria, yes in this case you would have development code and obfuscate before production. Anyways I completely agree. Just do not do it with html, css or js unless you have a real serious reason and a timeline/budget for it. Its like trying to hide behavior from the user and this is just a anti trust scheme in it self.

Comment: @AnaMaria Unless they use one of the [available](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deobfuscator/) [deobfuscators](http://www.kahusecurity.com/2012/revelo-javascript-deobfuscator/). I'd suggest minifying Javascript for production use (which does make it a little harder to read) to save on bandwidth & load times, but wouldn't bother obfuscating.

Comment: @LightningDust, I totally agree. I wouldnt bother with securing my javascript. Just provided a Link to the OP

Answer (score 1):

If you have a novel algorithm that you would like to hide from the public, the only way to do this is to use server-side code. Ex: ASP.NET, PHP, Python (Django), Ruby, etc. You can't hide javascript, only obfuscate it (Well, unless you use serverside js. see: node.js). Obfuscating code only really slows down a persistent person.

If you want to password protect certain portions of your site, again, the way to do this is with server-side code, a database, and an implementation of Users/Roles.